# Installing a non-natural comparator in an *extension* of TreeSet

Tags: java

I am trying to make an extension of TreeSet and to put in it my own comparator. Implementing the Comparator interface does not work:

```
class MyTreeSet<E> extends TreeSet<E> implements Comparator<E>{

    // the required implementation of the abstract compare(E,E):
    public int compare(E e1, E e2)
    {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

as evidenced by null obtained from

```
(new MyTreeSet<E>).comparator()
```

I do realize that a plain TreeSet with an arbitrary comparator can be obtained as

```
TreeSet<E> = new TreeSet<>(MyComparator<E> ctor)
```

where I have defined MyComparator separately. But I need a MyTreeSet which is an extension of TreeSet.  Is that possible?  Thanks.

Comment: "But I need a MyTreeSet which is an extension of TreeSet" Why?

Comment: Because I have additional methods that do things for me.

Comment: Please show them in your question then, because it's not apparent.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you are trying to use inheritance where composition would be more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe. I'll rethink the scheme. Thanks.